# Extend javafx.scene.paint.Color by getRGB method

Tags: swing, oop, inheritance, javafx, composition

I am converting my SWING application to JavaFX application. The swing application makes use of the java.awt.Color.getRGB() method.

javafx.scene.paint.Color does not have the getRGB() method. Therefore I wanted to extend the  javafx.scene.paint.Color and give it a self-written getRGB() method using the following logic

```
public int getRGB( Color col) 
{
    int r = ((int)col.RED.getRed()*255);
    int g = ((int)col.RED.getGreen() * 255);
    int b = ((int)col.RED.getBlue() * 255);
    int rgb = (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
    return rgb;
}
```

Unfortunately, javafx.scene.paint.Color is defined final and therefore does not allow to be extended.

My question: Which OO technic should I use to implement the self-written getRGB() method ? I could use composition but maybe there are smarter solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a utility class with a static helper method:

```
public static int getRGB( Color col)
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is simple and clean